# What would cause Chrome to maximize with cut off edges?

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors

The screen in question is an external monitor attached by HDMI to a laptop.

When I maximize Slack on the external screen, it fits perfectly.

When I maximize Chrome on the external screen, all edges are cut off.  When I drag Chrome to the right(my OS is Windows 10), it sizes perfectly.

What would cause Chrome to maximize off the screen edges when other programs seem to work fine?

Comment: are your monitors the same pixel dimensions? Is one a higher resolution and if so, do you have high-dpi adjustments?

Comment: @Yorik yes, the laptop is a higher resolution; not sure what you mean by having high-dpi adjustments

Comment: So high-dpi means that more pixels are packed into a smaller physical surface area. This can make user interface elements hard to see, so newer OS use dpi-scaling to scale things up, configuring is in display properties and possibly video driver configuration. If you set up dpi scaling for your monitor, Windows is drawing everything larger. Not all programs are dpi-aware. So in your example you probably have some programs that are dpi aware and some that are not, and so this scaling and resolution mismatch *might be* the cause of your cropping issue on the secondary monitor.